# How to install a 32-bit binary using Cabal

Tags: haskell, 32-bit, cabal, i386

I'm running Ubuntu Precise with an amd64 kernel and amd64 userland. I've just installed Haskell using `sudo apt-get install haskell-platform`. Now I'd like to install a binary using `cabal install ...`. However, that generates an amd64 binary. How is it possible to make Cabal generate an i386 binary (e.g. like `gcc -m32`) without creating a chroot of a full i386 Ubuntu system (using debootstrap) or creating a virtual machine, or running it on an i386 userland?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an i386 binary of GHC from the [official download site](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_6_3#x86linux). It is safe to install multiple versions of GHC alongside each other (though I'm not sure whether it handles multiple architectures for a single version gracefully). You can then instruct cabal which compiler to use with its `-w` option.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. *haskell-platform* includes GHC, but it contains many more, so I guess I'd have to install everything else manually.